# XmlDocument to DataSet only returning 1 Row

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint-2010, dataset, xmldocument

I have an problematic piece of code and it's something really peculiar and nothing I've ever experienced before!

I'm calling a Sharepoint SOAP function and the results are being returned absolutely fine., many XML records of data are being retruned.

Now I have tried to convert the results into an XmlDocument, which I then use to load into a DataSet.

However when it gets inserted into the DataSet it's only inserting 1 record, which happens to be the very first record of the Xml.

The problematic code is the below:

```
            Lists list = new Lists();               
            list.Url = URL + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
            list.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            //Gets the entire Lists attached to the Sharepoint Site
            XmlNode Results = list.GetListCollection();

           //Writes the entire results into an XmlDocument.
            doc.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(Results, true));


            using (StringReader xmlSR = new StringReader(doc.InnerXml))
            {
                ds.ReadXml(xmlSR, XmlReadMode.Auto);
            }
```

The Xml from 'doc.InnerXml' is all valid and is pastable into Xml Notepad 2007, so i'm a bit at a lost.

I hope someone can shed some light onto this, be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example works for me:

```
Lists list = new Lists(); //SharePoint Lists SOAP service

//Perform request
XmlNode result = list.GetListCollection();


//Process result
var ds = new DataSet("ListsResults");
using (var reader = new StringReader(result.OuterXml))
{
    ds.ReadXml(reader, XmlReadMode.Auto);
}

//print List Titles
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     Console.WriteLine(row["Title"]);
}
```

---

Another common approach is to utilize `LINQ to XML`:

```
Lists list = new Lists(); //SharePoint Lists SOAP service

//Perform request
XmlNode result = list.GetListCollection();


var docResult = XDocument.Parse(result.OuterXml);
XNamespace s = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
var listEntries = from le in docResult.Descendants(s + "List")
                          select new
                              {
                                  Title = le.Attribute("Title").Value
                              };
foreach (var e in listEntries)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.Title);
}
```